# MySQL triggers concatenation string

Tags: mysql, string, triggers, concatenation

the problem is when I'm trying to set the CAD Variable!

how I can get the concatenation Here is my sample code:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE vUser varchar(50);

  set @cad: = "The user "+ vUser+ " add the jurisdiction "+ NEW.name;


  INSERT INTO ActivyLog
  VALUES
  (null,'Jurisdiction added', @cad, now(), now(), '1' , '1' );

END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CONCAT("The user ", vUser, " add the jurisdiction ", NEW.name)
```

try this

Comment: it does work, this is the correct answer. CONCAT bring together strings.